# It's Your Turn ! (Renju)

Tags: code-golf, board-game

*EDITS*:

- Added link to the plain-text (multiple strings) test data
- Added BLANK,EDGE and TIE2 test cases (see Test Data section) (11/25)
- Updated the JSON test cases (some lines were ill-formatted) (11/24)

[image: Renju match gone bad !]

Renju match gone bad ! (well, technically these guys are playing Go, but who cares) [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Game_of_Go_(annotated)/Chapter_I)

## TL;DR

Take a 15x15 grid of characters (made of **'.'**, **'0'** and **'*'**), as an input, replace one of **'.'** s with **'*'**, 
in such a way that an unbroken horizontal, vertical or diagonal line of exactly five '*' chars is formed.

```
           *        *    * 
           *       *      *
 ******    *      *        *
           *     *          *
           *    *            *
```

Output the coordinates of your **'*'**, or string - **'T'** if there is no solution.

Creating a line of more than 5 **'*'** long (directly or indirectly) is not allowed, this is called an "overline".

Some examples of overlines:

```
 ****.** - replacing . with * will result in a horizontal overline


 *.***  - replacing . with * will result in a diagonal overline 
   *
    *
     *
      *
       *
```

## Full Version

**Abstract**

[Renju](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renju) - is an abstract strategy board game (a simpler version of it is also known as Gomoku).

The game is played with *black* and *white* stones on a 15×15 gridded *Go* board.

*Black* plays first if *white* did not just win, and players alternate in placing a stone of their color on an empty intersection. 
The winner is the first player to get an unbroken row of five stones horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

Computer search by L. Victor Allis has shown that on a 15×15 board, *black* wins with perfect play.
This applies regardless of whether overlines are considered as wins.

Renju eliminates the "Perfect Win" situation in Gomoku by adding special conditions for the first player (*Black*).

(c) Wikipedia

**Objective**

Consider you are a part of a Renju match, you are playing black, and there is just one turn left for you to win.

Take the current board position as an input, identify one of the winning moves (if there is one), and output it (see below for the data formats and restrictions).

Sample input board:

```
    A B C D E F G H J K L M N O P       . - vacant spot (intersection) 
 15 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 15    0 - white stone
 14 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 14    * - black stone
 13 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 13    X - the winning move
 12 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 12    
 11 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 11
 10 . . . . . . . 0 . . . . . . . 10
  9 . . . . . . . * . . . . . . .  9
  8 . . . . . . . * . . . . . . .  8
  7 . . . 0 . . . * . . . . . . .  7
  6 . . . 0 0 . . * . . . . . . .  6
  5 . . . . . . . X . . . . . . .  5
  4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  4
  3 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  3
  2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  2
  1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  1
    A B C D E F G H J K L M N O P
```

(axis labels are for illustration purposes only and *are not* part of the input)

Sample output:

```
H5
```

**Rules**

For the purpose of this challenge, only the following subset of Renju rules apply:

- You can place your stone on any vacant intersection (spot);
- Player who achieved an unbroken row of five stones horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, wins;
- Black (you) may not make a move which will result (directly or indirectly) in creation of an "overline" i.e. six or more black stones in a row.

**Data Formats**

Input data is a 15x15 grid of characters (".","*","0"]), ASCII-encoded, in any acceptable format, e.g. a two-dimensional character array or a newline separated set of strings e.t.c.

You *may not* however modify the input alphabet in any way.

Output data is a string, denoting the alpha-numeric board position, as illustrated by the sample board above.

Note that original horizontal axis numeration (A..P), does not include 'I', you *MAY* use 'A..O' instead, w/o penalty.

If there is no winning move available, output "T" instead.

**Scoring**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins !

**Some Tests Cases**

*Tie*

Input:

```
    A B C D E F G H J K L M N O P
 15 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 15
 14 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 14
 13 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 13
 12 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 12
 11 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 11
 10 . . . . . . . 0 . . . . . . . 10
  9 . . . . . . . * . . . . . . .  9
  8 . . . . . . . * . . . . . . .  8
  7 . . . 0 . . . * . . . . . . .  7
  6 . . . 0 0 . . * . . . . . . .  6
  5 . . . . . . . Z . . . . . . .  5
  4 . . . . . . . * . . . . . . .  4
  3 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  3
  2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  2
  1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  1
    A B C D E F G H J K L M N O P
```

Output:

```
 "T", the only "winning move" is H5 (denoted with "Z"), but that would create an overline H4-H9
```

*Overline*

Input:

```
    A B C D E F G H J K L M N O P
 15 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 15
 14 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 14
 13 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 13
 12 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 12
 11 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 11
 10 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 10
  9 . . . . . 0 . . . . 0 . . . .  9
  8 . . 0 . . . . . . * 0 0 . . .  8
  7 . . 0 . . . . . * . . 0 . . .  7
  6 . . 0 * . 0 . * . . 0 0 . . .  6
  5 . . 0 . * . * X * * * . . . .  5
  4 . . . . . Z . . . . . . . . .  4
  3 . . . . . . * . . . . . . . .  3
  2 . . . . . . . * . . . . . . .  2
  1 . . . . . . . . * . . . . . .  1
    A B C D E F G H J K L M N O P
```

Output:

```
 "H5", the other possible winning move is "F4", but that would result in J1-D6 diagonal overline.
```

*Multiple winning moves*

Input:

```
    A B C D E F G H J K L M N O P
 15 . * * * . . * * * . . . . . . 15
 14 . * . . . . . * . . * . . . . 14
 13 . * . . . . . . . . . . . * . 13
 12 . . . . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 . * . 12
 11 . . . . 0 . . X . . . 0 . * * 11
 10 . . . . 0 X * * * * X 0 . . * 10
  9 . . . . 0 . . * . . . 0 . * *  9
  8 . . . . 0 0 . * . . 0 0 . * .  8
  7 . . . . . 0 . * . . 0 . . * .  7
  6 . . . . . 0 . X . . 0 . . . .  6
  5 . . . . . 0 0 0 0 0 0 . . . *  5
  4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  4
  3 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  3
  2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  2
  1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  1
    A B C D E F G H J K L M N O P
```

Output:

```
"H6" or "H11" or "F10" or "L10" (one of)
```

**Test Data**

The test data in a bit more machine-friendly form (JSON) is available [HERE](http://pastebin.com/4rZKphB6)

Added BLANK,EDGE and TIE2 test cases: [UPDATED TEST SUITE](http://pastebin.com/XBd6gBxk)

You can use the following JS snippet to convert it to multiline strings, if necessary:

```
for(B in RENJU) { console.log(B+"\n"+RENJU[B].map(l=>l.join``).join`\n`); }
```

or just download them [here](http://pastebin.com/LRGV7651)

Comment: I'd recommend giving the test cases as they'd appear to the program, not in the form that's clearest for a human to see. That will make it much easier to test submissions.

Comment: @ais523 - I've posted JSON-formatted input data for the test cases to the Pastebin (see my update)

Comment: Jesus George! Can we please have columns from `A` to `O` instead of `A` to `H` and `J` to `P`!?!

Comment: @Titus, sure, I'll update the rules now to allow for this

Comment: Is it not promised that black and white are same amount?

Comment: > Is it not promised that black and white are same amount?

It is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 161

Input as multiline string.

Note: could save 1 byte using `A..O` instead of `A..P`

```
s=>[...s].some((q,p)=>([1,15,16,17].map(d=>x=(q=((r=p=>s[p-d]=='*'?r(p-d):p)(a=p)-r(p,d=-d))/d)>x?q:x,x=q!='.'&&5),x==4))?'ABCDEFGHJKLMNOP'[a%16]+(15-(a>>4)):'T'
```

*Less golfed*

```js
s=>
[...s].some( 
  (q, p) => // execute for each character q in position p, stop when true
  (
    [1, 15, 16, 17].map( // offset for 4 directions
      d => // for each direction d
      (
        // recursive function to find adjacent '*' in direction -d
        r = p => s[p-d] == '*' ? r(p-d) : p,
        // I need 4 adjacent '*' in at least 1 direction
        // but no more in any direction
        a = p, // current position in a, could be the answer
        q = r(p), // look back (reuse variable q)
        d = -d, q -= r(p), // then look forward
        q = q/d, // number of '*' in q
        x = q > x ? q : x // keep the max in any direction
      ),
      // init x to 0 if the current position is empty
      // else init x to 5, so it will be not valid in any case (too big)
      x = q !='.' && 5
    ),
    // if 4 '*' found, exit the loop
    x==4
  )
) // return true if solution found (solution in a)
? 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNOP'[a % 16] + (15 - ( a >> 4))
: 'T'
```

**Test**

```js
F=
s=>[...s].some((q,p)=>([1,15,16,17].map(d=>x=(q=((r=p=>s[p-d]=='*'?r(p-d):p)(a=p)-r(p,d=-d))/d)>x?q:x,x=q!='.'&&5),x==4))?'ABCDEFGHJKLMNOP'[a%16]+(15-(a>>4)):'T'

out=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n\n'

;renju = {
"BLANK":"...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............",
"EDGE":"...........****\n.0.............\n.0.............\n.0.............\n.00000.........\n.....0.........\n.....0.........\n.....0.........\n.....0.........\n...............\n...............\n.....*........*\n....*.........*\n...*..........*\n..*...........*",
"TIE":"...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n.......0.......\n.......*.......\n.......*.......\n...0...*.......\n...00..*.......\n...............\n.......*.......\n...............\n...............\n...............",
"TIE2":"...............\n.....0****000..\n...............\n.*0............\n..*.0..........\n..0*...0.......\n.......*.......\n.......*.......\n.......*.00....\n.......*.......\n.......0.......\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............",
"OVERLINE":"...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n...............\n.....0....0....\n..0......*00...\n..0.....*..0...\n..0*.0.*..00...\n..0.*.*.***....\n...............\n......*........\n.......*.......\n........*......",
"MULTIPLE":"...............\n...............\n...............\n.....0000000...\n....0......0...\n....0.****.0...\n....0..*...0...\n....00.*..00...\n.....0.*..0....\n.....0....0....\n.....000000....\n...............\n...............\n...............\n..............."
};

for(k in renju) {
  var r=F(renju[k])
  out(k+' '+r+'\n   ABCDEFGHJKLMNOP\n'+renju[k].split`\n`.map((v,i)=>(115-i+' ').slice(1)+v).join`\n`)
}
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: So you need the parens around `15-(a>>4)`?

Comment: @ZacharyT yes. `String + number - number === NaN`

Comment: `s=>[...s].some((q,p)=>([1,15,16,17].map(d=>x=(q=((r=p=>s[p-d]=='*'&&1+r(p-d))(a=p)+r(p,d=-d)))>x?q:x,x=q!='.'&&5),x==4))?'ABCDEFGHJKLMNOP'[a%16]+(15-(a>>4)):'T'`? (1B save)

Comment: `s=>[...s].some((q,p)=>([1,15,16,17].map(d=>x=(q=((r=p=>s[p-d]=='*'&&.1+r(p-d))(a=p)+r(p,d=-d)))>x?q:x,x=q!='.'),x==.4))?'ABCDEFGHJKLMNOP'[a%16]+(15-(a>>4)):'T'` add 0.1 instead of 1 to omit `&&5`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>205</s> <s>203</s> <s>201</s> <s>246</s> <s>257</s> 238 bytes

requires PHP<7.1 (relies on empty negative string offsets)

third approach, finally really complete, and I think I have left nothing to golf.

```
for($p=240;(!$l|$o)&&$p--;)for($k=4,$l=$o=0;$k--;$l|=preg_match("#\*{5}#",$s),$o+=preg_match("#\*{6}#",$s))for($s="*",$i=0;"."==($g=$argv[1])[$p]&&$i++<5;)$s=$g[$p-$i*$d=!$k?:$k+14].$s.$g[$p+$d*$i];echo$p<0?T:chr(65+$p%16).(15-($p/16|0));
```

takes multiline string with Linux style linebreaks (1 character) from command line argument.
For 2 character linebreak: add one each to `14`, `15` and `16` and replace `240` with `255`.

Run with `-r`.

**breakdown**

```
for($p=240;(!$l|$o)&&$p--;)     // loop through positions while (no line or has overlines)
    for($k=4,$l=$o=0;$k--;          // loop through four directions
        $l|=preg_match("#\*{5}#",$s),   // post condition: set flag for line
        $o+=preg_match("#\*{6}#",$s)    // and count overlines
        )
        for($s="*",                     // assume asterisk at current position
            $i=0;
            "."==($g=$argv[1])[$p]      // if character is "."
            &&$i++<5;)                  // look 5 fields in +/- direction:
            $s=$g[$p-$i*
                $d=!$k?:$k+14               // map [3,2,1,0] to offset [17,16,15,1]
            ].$s.$g[$p+$d*$i];              // add characters
                                // output
echo$p<0?T:chr(65+$p%16).(15-($p/16|0));
```

uses columns `A..O`. For `A..H`+`J..P`, append `+($p/8&1)` to the `chr` parameter.

Comment: Nice, but does this work for "Tie" and "Overline" test cases ? (I can not recognize any overline detection code)

Comment: @zeppelin: At the top or bottom of the board, empty strings will be appended to `$s` and `strlen` will never hit `5`. And if `$s` contains newline or `0`, the `preg_match` will fail.

Comment: Well, I meant the "overline", as defined by the rules, i.e. a string 6 or more '*' long,  within the board (take a look at "Tie" and "Overline" test case illustrations).

Comment: @zeppelin: Oh I missed that one. I guess that will require some editing. Probably easier with the other approach that I´m currently working on.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 46 bytes

```
ṭ³Ṛœẹ”*¤ŒṬµ;Z;ŒD;ŒdŒrẎḢƇṀf5
Ṛœẹ”.ÇƇḢṚịØA,ɗ/ȯ”T
```

[Try it online! (OVERLINE testcase)](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzrWHNj/cOevo5Ie7dj5qmKt1aMnRSQ93rjm01TrK@ugkFyBOOTqp6OGuvoc7Fh1rf7izIc2UC0m93uF2oOiORUChh7u7D89w1Dk5Xf/EeqBMyP///6OV9FCBkg6tRQzgBFjEACKrZWCAKqIFYUBEtIBskACSGi0Q1NIiYLsWpnu0MF0IFVKKBQA)

[44 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzrWHNh@d/HDXzkcNc7UOLTk66eHONYe2WkdZH53kAsQpRycVPdzV93DHomPtD3c2pJlywRTrHW4HCu1Y9HDnrIe7uw/PcNQ5OV3/xHqgTMj///@jlfRQgZIOrUUM4ARYxAAiq2VggCqiBWFARLSAbJAAkhotENTSImC7FqZ7tDBdCBVSigUA) if you allow indexing the rows from top to bottom or taking them in reverse order.

[TIE testcase](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzrWHNj/cOevo5Ie7dj5qmKt1aMnRSQ93rjm01TrK@ugkFyBOOTqp6OGuvoc7Fh1rf7izIc2UC0m93uF2oOiORUChh7u7D89w1Dk5Xf/EeqBMyP///6OV9FCBkg61RQwwRLQIiBhgihhg06VHhMkkuTkWAA)

[MULTIPLE testcase](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzrWHNj/cOevo5Ie7dj5qmKt1aMnRSQ93rjm01TrK@ugkFyBOOTqp6OGuvoc7Fh1rf7izIc2UC0m93uF2oOiORUChh7u7D89w1Dk5Xf/EeqBMyP///6OV9FCBkg7xIgYQgBAxgMijiGgBAaqInhaaGgOQCLI5ehARFLvgBKrtpLoZr0gsAA)

### Explanation

```
ṭ³Ṛœẹ”*¤ŒṬµ;Z;ŒD;ŒdŒrẎḢƇṀf5   Auxiliary monadic link, takes a pair of coordinates
ṭ                             Append the pair to
       ¤                      (
 ³                              The input
  Ṛ                             Reverse
   œẹ”*                         Find all coordinates of "*"
       ¤                      )
        ŒṬ                    Create a matrix with 1s at these coordinates and 0s everywhere else
          µ                   With this matrix:
           ;                  Join with
            Z                   the columns
             ;                Join with
              ŒD                diagonals
                ;             Join with
                 Œd             antidiagonals
                   Œr         Run-length encode each subarray into pairs of [item, length]
                     Ẏ        Shallow flatten
                       Ƈ      Find pairs where
                      Ḣ         the first item is truthy (and remove the item)
                        Ṁ     Maximum (by the length, since the item has been removed)
                         f5   Filter 5. This creates [5] (truthy) if the longest run has length exactly 5, and [] (falsy) otherwise.

Ṛœẹ”.ÇƇḢṚịØA,ɗ/ȯ”T   Main monadic link, takes a list of strings
Ṛ                    Reverse
 œẹ”.                Find all coordinates of "."
      Ƈ              Find those for which
     Ç                 the auxiliary link gives a truthy result
       Ḣ             First item, or 0 if the list is empty
        Ṛ            Reverse
              /      Fold under the following operation
             ɗ       (
         ị             Index the first item into
          ØA             the uppercase alphabet
            ,          Pair with the second item
             ɗ       )
               ȯ     Logical OR with
                ”T   "T"
```